# Implicit Trigonometry Differentiation Word Problem

Tags: trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

Two trains leave a station at the same time on tracks that are 60° to each other. One train travels at 80 km/h and the other travels at 100 km/h. At what rate are the trains separating 2 hours later?

I tried cosine law implicit differentiation but the answer is not even close to making sense. I'm not sure where my error lies.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks very much for the info. I'll be sure to attend to this in future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the intention of this exercise is to use related rates and - as mentioned in the header - implicit differentiation.

So, if $d(t)$ denotes the distance between the trains at time $t$ and if $v_1,v_2$ denote the two velocities, you have according to the law of cosines

$$d^2(t) = (v_1t)^2+ (v_2t)^2 - 2v_1v_2t^2\cos 60° = (v_1^2+v_2^2-v_1v_2)t^2$$

Implicit differentiation gives

$$2d(t)\dot d(t) = 2(v_1^2+v_2^2-v_1v_2)t$$

or
$$\dot d(t) = \frac{(v_1^2+v_2^2-v_1v_2)t}{d(t)} = \frac{(v_1^2+v_2^2-v_1v_2)t}{t\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2-v_1v_2}} = \sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2-v_1v_2}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the cosine law,

$$\frac d{dt}\sqrt{v_0^2t^2+v_1^2t^2-2v_0v_1t^2\cos\theta}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Relative velocity is the vector difference of (uniform) velocity vectors.

$$v_{rel}=\sqrt{v_1^2+ v_2^2 - 2 v_1 v_2 \cos \gamma}$$
$$=\sqrt{100^2+ 80^2 - 100*80}$$

Comment: That is the answer my key provides (thank you for confirming) but I cannot solve with physics formulas for marks as this is a Intro Calculus class.

Comment: @Kay But this is just the law of cosines.

Comment: @AndrewChin solving that way still considers the velocities as vectors (physics) rather than rates of change (maths). Or perhaps I am overthinking it... It works with both methods, I'm just not sure of my instructor's expectations. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I forgot to put in cos 60 before differentiating as it is an unchanging value. This makes the derivative massively easier to compute.

Answer: 91.65 km/h

Thanks for the feedback and help!

PS I'm not sure why I got down voted after I edited my post? Sorry, I'm new to this forum and not sure of the expectations for posting. :/